# Unable to get .key from .pem

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

For example I have the above as test.pem file, and I tried:

```
openssl rsa -in test.pem -out test.key
openssl pkey -in test.pem -out test.key
```

I got errors:

```
unable to load Private Key
4611995244:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:697:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

unable to load key
4771477100:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:697:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the certificate's public key, the command you are looking for is (in **OpenSSL 1.1.0 or greater**):

`openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -out key.pem -in cert.pem`

- `x509`: the x509 certificate manipulation command.
- `-pubkey`: tell the command to write the certificate's public key in the output.
- `-noout`: tell the command to not print the certificate in the output.
- `-out <file>`: defines the file to print the output to.
- `-in <file>`: defines the certificate to be interpreted.

If you are using **OpenSSL 1.0.2**, use:

`openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > key.pem`

Comment: it generates an empty `key.pem`

Comment: perhaps `openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > cert.key`

Comment: I just tested with the certificate you posted and it worked. What is your openssl version? You can run `openssl version` to get the version. You can also run `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text` to check if the openssl can interpret your certificate.

Comment: `openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018`

Comment: Yeh, OpenSSL 1.0.2 doesn't redirect the `-pubkey` output to the `-out <file>` parameter. I updated my answer to include that. Your suggestion is valid.